# Which module I can disable in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am working on a website in Magento 2, but many of the modules are not of my use because my target customers would be from INDIA for now.

Also, I only want to sell **simple**, **virtual** and **downloadable** products. I don't want **configurable**, **bundled** and **grouped** products.

I don't want payment methods like **Authorizenet**, **Braintree**, and **PayPal**, shipping methods like **DHL**, **UPS** and **USPS**.

So, my question is how can I remove these modules from my Magento project without harming the other functionality of Magento 2?

I have already tried https://www.integer-net.com/why-and-how-to-disable-magento-2-core-modules-improve-performance/ but it broke Magento's functionality.

Please suggest, which modules can be removed from Magento 2 safely and how to make it work without breaking default functionality of store?

Is there any automated tool to check the list of modules which will not affect on other modules functionality?

I don't have any plan to upgrade my store using the command line. I would prefer replacing my store modules directly in future (if needed).

Answer (score 3):

After some time investment, I have found success in finding modules which can be disabled based on the above criteria.

Below is the list of modules which can be disabled:

- **Magento_AdminNotification** (Some extensions may need this module to show notifications)
- **Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport** (May be enabled as per requirement)
- **Magento_BundleImportExport** (Since I don't need bundled products in my website) (May be enabled as per requirement)
- **Magento_ConfigurableImportExport** (Since I don't need configurable products in my website) (May be enabled as per requirement)
- **Magento_ConfigurableProductSales** (Since I don't need configurable products in my website) (May be enabled as per requirement)
- **Magento_CustomerImportExport** (Initially I don't need to import customers)
- **Magento_Dhl** (Not required as mentioned in the question)
- **Amazon_Core** (Not required as mentioned in the question)
- **Magento_Authorizenet** (Not required as mentioned in the question)
- **Magento_Fedex** (Not required as mentioned in the question)
- **Magento_GoogleAdwords** (Not required)
- **Magento_GroupedImportExport** (Not required since I am not using grouped products)
- **Magento_DownloadableImportExport** (Not required initially)
- **Magento_Marketplace** (Not required)
- **Magento_Multishipping** (Not required)
- **Magento_NewRelicReporting** (Not required)
- **Klarna_Core** (Not required)
- **Magento_Persistent** (Not required)
- **Amazon_Login** (Not required)
- **Magento_QuoteAnalytics** (Not required)
- **Magento_ReleaseNotification** (Not required)
- **Magento_SendFriend** (Not required)
- **Magento_ReviewAnalytics** (Not required)
- **Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable** (Not required, since configurable products are not required)
- **Amazon_Payment** (Not required, as mentioned in the question)
- **Klarna_Ordermanagement** (Not required, as mentioned in the question)
- **Magento_Signifyd** (Not required)
- **Magento_Swagger** (Not required, since there is some problem in swagger module currently)
- **Magento_Swatches** (Not required, since configurable products are not required)
- **Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation** (Not required, since configurable products are not required)
- **Magento_TaxImportExport** (Not required, as initially I would configure from the backend)
- **Klarna_Kp** (Not required, as mentioned in the question)
- **Magento_GoogleOptimizer** (Not required)
- **Magento_Ups** (Not required, as mentioned in the question)
- **Magento_SampleData** (Not required)
- **Magento_Usps** (Not required, as mentioned in the question)
- **Magento_Braintree** (Not required, as mentioned in the question)
- **Magento_Version** (Not required, since I know my Magento version)
- **Dotdigitalgroup_Email** (Not required)
- **Magento_WishlistAnalytics** (Not required)
- **Shopial_Facebook** (Not required)
- **Temando_Shipping** (Not required, since flat shipping is sufficient currently)
- **Vertex_Tax** (Not required, since target country is only one)

As per requirement, any module in above list can be enabled (including their respective dependencies).