# Disable Ecommerce Modules from Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, magentomodule

So I am a lover of Magento Framework itself, but I want to build a normal website, nothing to do with ecommerce, so Taxes, products, categories, checkout, quotes, elastic search and etc its not necessary for the website I want to create.

The website itself its frontend based and some backend to integrations if needed.

So someone knows which modules I should disable to work it properly and create it?

Thanks in advanced :)

Answer (score 0):

You can review following question:

[Which module I can disable in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230090/which-module-i-can-disable-in-magento-2)

Apart from that, you may have to disable the following as well:

- Magento_Elasticsearch
- Magento_Elasticsearch6
- Magento_Elasticsearch7
- Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissions
- Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissionsGraphQl

Based on the result of disabling above modules, you may have to disable some more modules which are related to these.

Some modules (mentioned in the answer listed above) have been already removed by Magento. For example, Klarna_Ordermanagement, so you may need to make some decisions based on your Magento's version.

Answer (score -1):

You should disable these modules from the Magento

```
-Magento Checkout 
-Magento Products
-Magento Categories
-Magento Products
-Magento quotes
-Magento Elastic Search Modules
```

There are two ways to disable that modules

```
- If there is any configurations from Admin then disable it 
- Otherwise Disable from Config.php by changing Value from 1 to 0
```